# Getting values from dictionary using user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
Bavaria={'Number_of_solders':1500, 'Strength':5}
print ('Which country is attacking? ')
a=input()
print ('Number of attacking forces of '+a+' is '+a['Number_of_soldiers']+' men!')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
                                  line 6, in <module>
    print ('Number of attacking forces of '+a+' is '+a['Number_of_soldiers']+' men!')
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

How can  retrieve value or key from the dictionary, name of which is given by user?

Comment: because your trying to lookup the a variable, which is a string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your dictionary so that the name of the country is also a key:

```
countries = {'bavaria': {'soldiers': 1500, 'strength': 5}}
```

Now you can ask the user for the country:

```
a = input('Which country is attacking? ')
stats = countries.get(a.lower())
if stats:
    print('Number of soliders: {0[soldiers]} men!'.format(stats))
else:
    print('Sorry no stats for {0}'.format(a))
```